# Flask, Gunicorn, Mysqlconnctor /GET error on every refresh

Tags: python, mysql, flask, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I was making a pretty basic Flask app to display the tables of a  mysql database on a vps.

I ran the app via gunicorn, and it works fine and shows the tables, but every time I refresh the browser in the app, it breaks and returns the error below.

How do I fix this and make browser refreshes work in my app?
I have all of my files below

GUNICORN ERROR

```
:8880 wsgi:app
[2020-04-16 13:23:34 +0000] [3196] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-04-16 13:23:34 +0000] [3196] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8880 (319
6)
[2020-04-16 13:23:34 +0000] [3196] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-04-16 13:23:34 +0000] [3199] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3199
[2020-04-16 13:23:37 +0000] [3196] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
[2020-04-16 13:23:43,615] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi
_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full
_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in hand
le_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in re
raise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full
_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in disp
atch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/var/www/pi.sminfo.me/app.py", line 7, in display_tables
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pitemp;")
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_c
ext.py", line 233, in execute
    raise errors.ProgrammingError("Cursor is not connected")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Cursor is not connected
[2020-04-16 13:23:47 +0000] [3196] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
[2020-04-16 13:24:46 +0000] [3196] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
^C[2020-04-16 13:28:30 +0000] [3196] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2020-04-16 13:28:30 +0000] [3199] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3199)
[2020-04-16 13:28:30 +0000] [3196] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

APP.PY

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def display_tables():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pitemp;")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    db.close()
    cursor.close()
    return render_template("index.html", data=data)
```

db2.py

```
db = mysql.connector.connect (
    host="localhost",
    user="********",
    passwd="*******",
    database="*******"
)

cursor = db.cursor()
```

wgsi.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

/templates/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Rpi Temp Log</title>
<style>

h1 {
color: #C93F3F;
font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: left;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 50%;
color: #C93F3F;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 25px;
text-align: left;
}
th {
background-color: #3A3AEA;
color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div><img src="https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2011/10/Raspi-PGB001.png" width="200" height="200" align="left"/><h1>Raspberry Pi Temperature Logger </h1></div>


<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

{% for row in data %}
   <tr>
    {% for d in row %}
        <td>{{ d }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you’re directly closing the connection within your view:

```
@app.route('/')
def display_tables():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pitemp;")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    db.close() # CLOSED HERE
    cursor.close()
    return render_template("index.html", data=data)
```

That’s why multiple visits to that route will complain that you are trying to work with a closed connection.

Separately, you can’t maintain a database connection in this way. You haven’t shown how the connection is actually established – are you making this a `global` for your app? Gunicorn will spawn multiple processes which may each get their own global connection, or perhaps the connection is pre-forked. Either way, this will be confusing to debug or handle.

You should look into [`flask-sqlalchemy`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/) if you are just starting out, as that will ensure that your connection and sessions are managed each time a route is visited. Alternatively, you might want to take the approach of [Flask and SQLAlchemy without the Flask-SQLAlchemy Extension](https://nestedsoftware.com/2018/06/11/flask-and-sqlalchemy-without-the-flask-sqlalchemy-extension-3cf8.34704.html) or similar. If you don’t wish to use an ORM for this, you’ll need to consider how connections are established and torn down without the connection being global.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into SQLAlchemy